# Displays all the data with the select option in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to display data via select option based on the field division and successful , but how do I display all the data ?

Controllers

```
public function dokumen() 
{
    $divisi = $this->input->post('divisi'); 
    $data=array('title'         =>'KOPKAR - Pelanggan',     
                'divisi'        => $this->induk_internal->get_divisi(), 
                'get_dokumen'   => $this->induk_internal->get_dokumen($divisi),
                'isi'           =>'admin/DCR/daftarindukinternal'
    );          
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);              
}
```

Models

```
function get_dokumen($divisi) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('daftar_detail_internal');
    $this->db->where('divisi',$divisi);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Views

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="selectpicker" style="display: none;" name="divisi"  autofocus>
    <option value="if click show all data">ALL</option> 
        <?php foreach($divisi as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->divisi;?>"><?php echo $row->divisi;?>     
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: can you show the html that your view outputs?

Comment: and in `dokumen` maybe `print_r($this->induk_internal->get_dokumen($divisi))` to see the output

Comment: what do you mean by all the data ? please elaborate